# The `hue` parameter in Seaborn.relplot() skips an integer when given numerical data?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

The hue parameter skips one integer.

```
d = {'column1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'column2':[2,4,5,2,3], 'cluster':[0,1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sns.relplot(x='column2', y='column1', hue='cluster', data=df)
```

[image: While all points are plotted, the cluster label is missing '2'.]

*Python 2.7
Seaborn 0.9.0
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the output correct? Shouldn't `3, 5` be in cluster 4?

Comment: I couldn't post the output (because I don't have 10 reps), the 'hue' bar on the right side of the graph only labels 0,1,3,4 and skips label 2. But all the points are graphed regardless of their labels.

Comment: You should be able to post the output now :)

Comment: I know it has been almost two years since the question is asked but I thought it would be important to leave this reference here. By providing, legend='full'  you can plot each hue as category instead of numbers. Here is the link to seaborn dev: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1653

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### "Full" legend

If the `hue` is in numeric format, seaborn will assume that it represents some continuous quantity and will decide to display what it thinks is a representative sample along the color dimension.

You can circumvent this by using `legend="full"`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'column2':[2,4,5,2,3], 'cluster':[0,1,2,3,4]})
sns.relplot(x='column2', y='column1', hue='cluster', data=df, legend="full")
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Categoricals

An alternative is to make sure the values are treated categorical
Unfortunately, even if you plug in the numbers as strings, they will be converted to numbers falling back to the same mechanism described above. This may be seen [as a bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1515).

However, one choice you have is to use real categories, like e.g. single letters.

```
'cluster':list("ABCDE")
```

works fine,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'column1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'column2':[2,4,5,2,3], 'cluster':list("ABCDE")}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

sns.relplot(x='column2', y='column1', hue='cluster', data=df)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Strings with customized palette

An alternative to the above is to use numbers converted to strings, and then make sure to use a custom palette with as many colors as there are unique hues.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {'column1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'column2':[2,4,5,2,3], 'cluster':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["cluster"] = df["cluster"].astype(str)

sns.relplot(x='column2', y='column1', hue='cluster', data=df, 
            palette=["b", "g", "r", "indigo", "k"])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You may look at the [seaborn issue tracker](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues) if this issue has already been raised, and if not, open an issue about it.

Comment: There is one more alternative: use `palette=[ ... ]` where the list contains exactly as many colours as your categories. Say, for two categories, `palette = ["r", "b"]` gives you red and blue points.

Comment: Yep, I was in the middle of updating this.

Comment: after wasting half a day, I finally found this solution...   thank you!

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with `sns.pairplot` where I was using a numeric column for `hue` and seaborn didn't show all the categories, and interpolated a non-existent category. 

In my case it was fixed by changing the column to `str` type (I'm likely using a more recent version of seaborn compared to the original answer).