# Why is the legend shown in a Seaborn JointGrid incorrect?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am experimenting with `JointGrid` from `Seaborn`. I used `.plot_joint()` to plot my scatter plot, group-colored using the `hue` parameter. I have filtered my dataset to only include 2 of the 5 groups, to prevent too much overlap in the plots.

The plotted points appear correct, in that they match what I expect from the two groups I chose. Additionally, I double-checked my filtering by viewing the filtered dataframe. That too was correct as it contained only the two groups I chose.

However the legend that is automatically plotted along with the scatterplot is incorrect. It shows 4 groups (not sure why not 5), and the coloring is also incorrect. For 2 groups I would expect only the Red and Blue colors (the first 2 colors in the `Set1` palette), but my 2nd group is colored with the 4th color in the `Set1` palette.

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 4)
df_tmp = df[df.Kmeans_Clusters.isin([0, 3])].copy()

# initialize Joint Grid
grid = sns.JointGrid(data=df_tmp, x='MP', y='PTS')

# plot scatter (main plot)
grid = grid.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, data=df_tmp, hue='Kmeans_Clusters',
                       palette='Set1')

# plot marginal distplot for cluster 0, X & Y
sns.distplot(df_tmp[df_tmp.Kmeans_Clusters == 0].MP, ax=grid.ax_marg_x,
             vertical=False, color='firebrick', label='Cluster0')
sns.distplot(df_tmp[df_tmp.Kmeans_Clusters == 0].PTS, ax=grid.ax_marg_y,
             vertical=True, color='firebrick', label='Cluster0')

# plot marginal distplot for cluster 3, X & Y
sns.distplot(df_tmp[df_tmp.Kmeans_Clusters == 3].MP, ax=grid.ax_marg_x,
             vertical=False, color='steelblue', label='Cluster3')
sns.distplot(df_tmp[df_tmp.Kmeans_Clusters == 3].PTS, ax=grid.ax_marg_y,
             vertical=True, color='steelblue', label='Cluster3')

plt.suptitle('PTS vs MP, Cluster 0 & 3\n1982-2019', y=1.05, fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[jointgrid_incorrect_legend_and_coloring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrKrV.png)

--- Update---
I just tried this with a simple `scatterplot` (no `JointGrid`) and I can repeat my previous observation. Is there just something I am not understanding with the `hue` parameter and the `scatterplot()` function?

I do not see this issue with `lmplot()`

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 4)
df_tmp = df[df.Kmeans_Clusters.isin([0, 3])].copy()
sns.scatterplot(data=df_tmp, y='PTS', x='MP', hue='Kmeans_Clusters', palette='Set1')
plt.title('PTS vs MP\n1982-2019')
plt.xlabel('Minutes Played Annually')
plt.ylabel('Points Scored Annually')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Once I realized the problem was with scatterplot() and not JointGrid as I mentioned in my update comments, I was able to fine tune my google search. The workaround I ended up using is casting my hue variable ('Kmeans_Clusters') to String type and concatening it with non-numeric characters so it could not get interpreted as numeric in any way. If I didn't do this, I would get an attribute error. So, in the end, my hue variable's categories are now 'cl_#' instead of just # as before. The legend now shows only the two groups I filtered to and the correct first 2 colors in the palette I chose.

Answer (score 0):

Again, once I fine tuned my searches, I was able to find the solution. In fact, here's another stackoverflow question that asks the same thing and is answered in detail: [The `hue` parameter in Seaborn.relplot() skips an integer when given numerical data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525284/the-hue-parameter-in-seaborn-relplot-skips-an-integer-when-given-numerical-d).

Pasting the solution I used, as described in the link above:

"""
An alternative is to make sure the values are treated categorical Unfortunately, even if you plug in the numbers as strings, they will be converted to numbers falling back to the same mechanism described above. This may be seen as a bug.

However, one choice you have is to use real categories, like e.g. single letters.

'cluster':list("ABCDE")

works fine, 
"""