# partial multiple shaded plots using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have a time series data of my experiment having 8 electrode pairs impedance measurements with 25 timestamps. Experiment is performed 41 times. Data looks like this

[image]

I have created a shaded plot using seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timeStamps", y="signal",hue="EP", data=df)
```

which looks something like this

[image]

however, I do want the shaded plot look like below where I have skipped initial values of electrode pair 2-8.

[image]

Update:
Solved the problem with the advice from on the comments:

Deleted timestamps from dataframe with this code

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.EP ==2) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=2) |
                (df.EP ==3) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=4) | 
                (df.EP ==4) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=6) |
                (df.EP ==5) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=8) |
                (df.EP ==6) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=10) |
                (df.EP ==7) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=12) |
                (df.EP ==8) & (df.timeStamps>=1) & (df.timeStamps<=14)].index)
```

and the desired output

[image]

However, I do not know why EP is not from 1-8 but 0-10 in the graph labels? Is there anyway to change them?

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: So you just want to skip part of the data? You could copy the data frame (as it is not very large) and cut out what you don't want to show.

Comment: @NarendraPrasath sample data is in hyperlink Data or you want data to try with? thanks

Comment: @DavidWierichs Let me try it. thank you

Comment: @DavidWierichs thank you for the suggestion, its solved however labels showing 0-10 instead of 1-8. Is there anyway to change it? Thank you

Comment: That is because seaborn interprets numerical data types and makes the hue a continuous scale. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525284/the-hue-parameter-in-seaborn-relplot-skips-an-integer-when-given-numerical-d) You can use `legend='full'` to avoid this.

Comment: Btw. you could drop on the condition `(df.timeStamps<=2*df.EP-2)` instead of writing all cases out explicitly, if I see this correctly.